# Git can not detect new files added to repository, but can detect old files in repo

Tags: git, bash, ubuntu, github, commit

so I am new to using Git and uploading to a repo through terminal. I am currently using Ubuntu Bash subsystem for Windows.

Essentially, for my CS class, I have to upload a file onto a online repository. Everything was working fine until I actually had to add the file.

I cloned the online repository and placed my file into the correct directory. However, when I used

> git add .

and

> git commit -a

The terminal gave me a message declaring

> On branch master, Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'. Nothing to commit, working directory clean

This seems odd as I clearly added a file to the directory. So I used git files-ls to see which files were detected and noticed that the file I wish to upload was not there. I changed my current directory and tried that as well, no dice. I used ls after changing my directory, still no dice. Every file that was originally in the repo directory shows up except my newly added file.

Furthermore, I have tried changing the name of the file and file type, nothing seems to have an impact.

I am sorry if I am incredibly ignorant with what I am doing, I am trying to learn. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a `.gitignore` file ignoring the file you added?

Comment: no there is no .gitignore in the directory

Comment: Well then either you didn't do what you said you did, or git is horribly broken/bugged on your system. If you added a new file into your working directory, and then executed `git add .` where `.` means "the folder containing the new file" or "a parent folder of the folder containing the new file", `git add .` should've added it.

Comment: Also, "there is no .gitignore in the directory" might not mean anything if the directory where you added the file is a sub-folder of your repository and there is a .gitignore file further up the stack.

Comment: Easy way to check if you're got an ignore rule is to use git check-ignore: `git check-ignore -v <filepath>` It will display the file and rule used to exclude the file if one exists.

Comment: What happens if you add the file explicitly: `git add <file>`?

Comment: The file can't be found